# How to set date locale in mailchimp?

Tags: email, date, locale, date-format, mailchimp

I need to change the mailchimp locale `*|DATE:M y|*`. This gives Apr 2013 and I want Abr 2013 (Portuguese format). Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the date with a translate merge tag?

```
*|TRANSLATE:PT|* *|DATE:M y|*
```

http://blog.mailchimp.com/automatically-translate-your-emails-to-over-30-languages/

The list of language codes can be found here:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/is-it-possible-to-translate-content-in-multiple-languages

But the Portugese options are:

Portuguese (Brazil) = pt

Portuguese (Portugal) = pt_PT

Comment: I can't really be anymore specific. `*|TRANSLATE:PT|*` will translate whatever content in that area into Brazilian Portuguese, `*|TRANSLATE:pt_PT|*` will translate the content into Portuguese of Portugal.

Answer (score -3):

There you go

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_PT');
echo strftime("%b %d %Y");
```

this will output

```
Abr 18 2013
```

To format dates in other languages, you need to use the [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.setlocale.php) and [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) functions

Comment: He wants this in the text of the e-mail of mailchimp and not in PHP directly.