# Mailchimp - How to set date locale in a campaign?

Tags: php, date, email, tags, mailchimp

I'd like to display the Hebrew month automatically in my Mailchimp's newsletter. So I think I need to set the date locale to Herbew. How do I set the date locale?

I saw this similar [question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079996/how-to-set-date-locale-in-mailchimp#) but it doesn't work anymore. (maybe the functionality has changed?)

I'm using this [list](https://mailchimp.com/help/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet/) (cheat sheet) of Mailchimp tags.
Based on tag `*|DATE: F Y|*` and `*|TRANSLATE:HE|*` it should give me the desired result, but instead supplies me a list of languages to translate my page into and I just want the date locale to be set to Israel.

Information about PHP format and date locale: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. Would love if I was wrong though.

Comment: please add this in the comments section. this is not an answer